# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) xcode error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I just followed a Youtube video on creating a Flappy Bird game, everything went well until i wrote the code inside ViewController.m and I realized I'm getting an error which is really annoying, my code looks exactly like the video's code I guess.

```
duplicate symbol _HighScoreNumber in:
    /Users/SRaheem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flappy_Kurd-ajkqjbpuoredvudzovmfygqfuasr/Build/Intermediates/Flappy Kurd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flappy Kurd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Game.o
    /Users/SRaheem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flappy_Kurd-ajkqjbpuoredvudzovmfygqfuasr/Build/Intermediates/Flappy Kurd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flappy Kurd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Post your code from Game.m and ViewController.m. Or search for "HighScoreNumber" in those files, the error says it is defined in both places in the same scope.

Comment: here is Game.m  http://pastie.org/private/aclehtrzjw3bbaklqldbog and here is ViewController.m http://pastie.org/private/zotfnbievnls9jjpnpi8ta

Comment: As trojanfoe said HighScoreNumber is probably declared in both game.h and ViewController.h. You need to remove one of the declarations or mark it as "extern". If you remove not altogether you need to import the header file with the remaining declaration in both Game.m and ViewController.m file. trojanfoe's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably added the variable `HighScoreNumber` in a header file that's included by both `Game.m` and `ViewController.m`.

This declaration needs changing to `extern int HighScoreNumber;` (or whatever type it is) and it needs defining in a `.m` file (in `Game.m` for example).